# How to change images

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am developing simple windows phone 8 application. I want to play a song in it so after clicking on play button song should play and the image on play button should change to pause button.clicking on pause song should pause and images change to play button.. How to change the images?

Comment: How are you setting the image on the play button ? can you give some more details

Comment: actually I am taking on image control having image of grass. on that i am taking button control and that control having image of play. On click event of play i am writing code to play audio. till here it is working. but now i want that when i click on that button then image will change to pause image. and when we click on pause song should pause and image turns to play

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider to have two buttons one with play image and the other with the pause image and switch the visibilty of the buttons depending upon your needs, like when the song is not playing display the button with play image and when the song is playing collapse the play button and make the pause button visible. This not the solution you want to know just another way of doing it for your the solution you seek i'll need to know how you are setting the image on the play button.

**Edit**

there's a visibilty property in every control, by default the visibilty of a button is set to "Visible", if your buttons are named controls then you can access the buttons from your "code behind" in your click or tap events for the respective buttons

Suppose here the XAML for your buttons

```
            <Button x:Name="PlayButton"  Click="PlayButton_Click" Visibility="Visible"/>
            <Button x:Name="PauseButton" Click="Pause_Click" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
```

Here is the code behind for the events attched

```
        private void PlayButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PlayButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;  //Collapse the Play Button
        PauseButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;    // Make Pause Button visible

        /*your code for play here*/

    }

    private void Pause_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PlayButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;             //Make Play Button Visible
        PauseButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;    //Collapse Pause Button

        /*your code for pause here*/
    }
```

Comment: How to switch visibility

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It helps you

```
<Image Source="Your play button source" MouseLeftButtonUp="imgPlayPause_MouseLeftButtonUp" x:Name="imgPlayPause"/>
```

In code behind take a global vaiable

```
 bool IsPlay = false;
    private void imgPlayPause_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
    if(!IsPlay)
    {
    IsPlay = true;
    imgPlayPause.Source = Your Pause image source
//Set Bitmap Image as Image Source

    plyaSong functionality
    }
    else
    {
    IsPlay = false;
    imgPlayPause.Source = Your play image source
    //Set Bitmap Image as Image Source
    pause song functionality
    }
    }
```